How to create a data class for an API Response in Android Jetpack Compose?
The API response looks something like this:
{
    "result": [
        {
            "key": "facility",
            "data": {
                "food": {
                    "nm": "Food"
                },
                "ppeKit": {
                    "nm": "PPE kit"
                },
                "transport": {
                    "nm": "Transport"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

I want to store the data part of the API response to be stored in a data class like below:
data class ResultItem(
    val key: String,
    val data: String
)

I mean like food should be stored as key, Food should be stored as value; ppeKit should be stored as key, PPE Kit should be stored as value; and so on.
It should be such that for each data selected, I can find its key easily. Note that there more key value pairs in the data part of the result or none as well. So, how should I write my data class. Please give me the answer and explain.

You can use json to kotlin data class generator: https://json2kt.com/ . Just paste your json over there and it will generate data class for you

Are you using a library for sending the requests, like Retrofit?

You say you want your data class ResultItem to contain the data as a String. In the JSON, however, that is an object. Do you really want that to be converted to a String? How should that look? Something like this? "{ \"food\": { \"nm\": \"Food\" }, \"ppeKit\": { \"nm\": \"PPE kit\" }, \"transport\": { \"nm\": \"Transport\" } }"

I thought facility should  be stored as key?

data class TestModel(
        val result: List<Result>
    ) {
        data class Result(
            val `data`: Data,
            val key: String
        ) {
            data class Data(
                val food: Food,
                val ppeKit: PpeKit,
                val transport: Transport
            ) {
                data class Food(
                    val nm: String
                )
    
                data class PpeKit(
                    val nm: String
                )
    
                data class Transport(
                    val nm: String
                )
            }
        }
    }

Just Used This Plugin to generate data class form respose

I'm still not sure I understood what you try to achieve, but I would suggest something like this:
data class ResultItem(
    val key: String,
    val data: Map<String, String>,
)

One ResultItem will contain the content of an item in your JSON's "result" array. For the one item you provide in your example the ResultItem instance would look like this:
val item = ResultItem(
    key = "facility",
    data = mapOf(
        "food" to "Food",
        "ppeKit" to "PPE kit",
        "transport" to "Transport",
    ),
)

And now you can access the item's data map like this:
val ppeKit = item.data["ppeKit"] // returns "PPE kit"


If possible ask your Api dev to update the response as a list of strings i.e:
{
    "result": [
        {
            "key": "facility",
            "data": [
                    "Food",
                    "PPE kit",
                  "Transport"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Or you can use Volley or any Lightweight networking library like ION
https://github.com/koush/ion
from where you can successfully receive the response as a JSON object and you can process over that to get the desired value, but that can be tough as your response pattern is complex because you need to code hard to get everything.
Recommendation is to update your API response

The question is about modeling the data class. Nothing in your answer addresses that.
